# Filter records by categories SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to build a query, that will return books with all information including genres of that book.
I have 3 objects:
Book__c in which I have all information about books,
Genre__c in which I have all genres,
BookGenreAssociation__c in which I link book to genre.

My apex query right now looks like this:

```
String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Picture_Url__c, Author__r.Name, Author__r.Photo_Url__c' +
    ', (SELECT Genre__r.Name, Genre__r.Id FROM BookGenreAssociations__r)' + 
    ' FROM Book__c';
if(fieldName != null && search != null && fieldName != '' && search != '') {
    query += ' WHERE ' + fieldName + ' LIKE \'%' + search + '%\'';
}
if(max != null) {
    query += ' LIMIT ' + max;
}
if(page != null) {
    Integer offset = max * page;
    query += ' OFFSET ' + offset;
}
return Database.query(query);
```

I have here pagination, search by author or title and I want to add filtering by multiple genres (for example user wants to find books in Action and Adventure genres.

I tried doing something like this in query editor:

```
SELECT Name, (
    SELECT Genre__r.Name, Genre__r.Id
    FROM BookGenreAssociations__r
) 
FROM Book__c 
WHERE BookGenreAssociations__r IN ('Action', 'Adventure')
```

but BookGenreAssociations__r isn't recognized and even if it was, subquery returns multiple results, so if I'm not mistaken, I can't use IN operator.

I tried also with Count function, but it can't be used in where clause.

I don't want to edit subquery, because I need all genres associated with book in order to print them in LWC.
I don't want to filter records in apex, because pagination will be broken.
I don't want to query BookGenreAssociation__c first, because there is possibility that not all books will be associated with genres.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you're looking for here is a [*semi-join*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm) (It's the second section in the comparison operators documentation). It's very similar to the parent-child query in the SELECT clause, just located in the WHERE clause (and it must follow some other rules. If I recall, the SELECT in a semi-join can only return an Id).

The query you'd be looking for is then something like

```
[
  SELECT Name, (
    SELECT Genre__r.Name, Genre__r.Id
    FROM BookGenreAssociations__r
  ) 
  FROM Book__c 
  WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT Book__c 
    FROM BookGenreAssociations__c 
    WHERE Genre__r.Name IN ('Action', 'Adventure')
  )
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I only changed in semi-join BookGenreAssociations__c to BookGenreAssociation__c and it worked. Thanks!